# Make keys with specific character in their name optional

Tags: typescript

Say I have an object like:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  "b?": 2,
  "c?": 3
}
```

Its type currently is:

```
type Obj = {
  a: number;
  "b?": number;
  "c?": number;
}
```

Is there a way to create a type that accepts `obj` and converts its type to:

```
type Obj = {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
  c?: number;
}
```

Essentially making `b` and `c` optional.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it can be done, but why would your starting point be that odd type definition?

Comment: I'm trying to build typesafe routing. For example `/user/:userId?` should yield `type UserPath = { userId?: string }`.

Comment: Ah, got it. :-)

Comment: cld this do the trick ? 
```type Obj = {
  a: number;
  "b?": number;
  "c?": number;
} | {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
  c?: number;
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using template literal types and inference. Breaking it into parts (but we'll combine them at the end):

1. First we want to get the required properties:

   ```
   type MapRequiredKeys<T> = {
       [Key in keyof T as Key extends `${string}?` ? never : Key]: T[Key];
   };
   ```

   There, if `Key` matches the pattern `${string}?`, we leave it out by using `never` as the key; otherwise, we use the key. Using that on `typeof obj` gives us `{ a: number; }`.
2. Then we want the optional ones, and we want just the base part of the key, not the `?`. That's where `infer` comes in:

   ```
   type MapOptionalKeys<T> = {
       [Key in keyof T as Key extends `${infer BaseKey}?` ? BaseKey : never]?: T[Key];
   };
   ```

   We match `Key` against `${infer BaseKey}?` and then use `BaseKey` if it matches (leaving out the property entirely if it doesn't). We use `?` on it to make the property optional.
3. Combining them:

   ```
   type MapKeys<T> = MapRequiredKeys<T> & MapOptionalKeys<T>;

   type ObjType = MapKeys<typeof obj>;
   ```

   [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAIwA02uARPAPyVEBM5uMlwdRAzOQL4DcmTFACeABwCmMALJ5RAJXEBHAK4BLAE7iAJgGlxwiAB4AKgD5UGCjgDae4TFVgYAa30gAZjGP4IMOzHEADyhxMC1fAAMAEnRodUcAcx4aCJgaGDBxADdxdRgiOwBdImNbfUKBfiExSRlRAHlRKFVwPAAbOyMzCywWMvtHFzdPbzxffyCQsMiYx3dcmAAhMfE7ZNT05YhV-XyM7NzCmhL+iswqkQlpWU6TczQ6hRUNbVvugDJrhqaWsHa30wCapXepIYw1Cx1W6XcQeOBIQGYAD0SNwAD0aII2uJYEFiERQYhwVc0OgcCiYAB1EDqZwQKz4IgAFiY5wE2NxgQYBLBENJ5NR1Np9JYhBgLOYuHgRAAbAB2XjsnEBQKcHlEvkYAVUml0hliiUM6UweWSnDAIhyuWsqoclVM9XEyT8mAUgCi6nUNJ8MC04ggLy0+uZrJY1A4JoVDItMCtNqVnIArI7NWTXaiPV68mNff7A8HxaGpURKBAQABbSRxRKUM0wGNxxWYIA)

But we can combine them into a single type, which makes the hints that TypeScript gives us clearer:

```
type MapKeys<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T as Key extends `${string}?` ? never : Key]: T[Key];
} & {
    [Key in keyof T as Key extends `${infer BaseKey}?` ? BaseKey : never]?: T[Key];
};

type ObjType = MapKeys<typeof obj>;
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAIwA02uARPAPyVEBM5uMlwdRAzOQL4DcmTFACeABwCmMALJ5RAaXHCIAHgAqAPlQYKOANoLhMAJZgYAa0UgAZjFX4IMAzHEAPKOLAATBwAMAJOjQAE4mAOY8ND4wNDBg4gBu4kEwRAYAukSq+oppAjwwAGTaLNmGJuaWNnZ4Dk6u7l6+ASZWSTAAQjXiBhFRMZ0Q3YopsQlJaTSZpbmY-IIiEjAA8kiqYpJoMvKKKgvi1nBI6gIA9Ce4AHo0ggA24rCuxEQriGuLaFgsZzAA6iBBZggOnwRAALExZgI7g8XAxnqt1lpPrhvn8AUCWIQYODmLh4EQAGwAdl4UPuzhcnHhr0RH2BqP+gOBWJxwPxMGJuJwwCIRKJELm0IpoOpbw2xRR5wAokEgv97DBPOIIEYguJPMywRCWNQOByScCeTA+QKyTCAKyi2kSnDfGVy5I1RXK1XqzXY7V4oiUCAgAC2kmCYUoXJgRpNpKAA)

If you hover `ObjType` there, you see `type ObjType = { a: number; } & { b?: number | undefined, c?: number | undefined; }` instead of seeing the "calls" to `MapRequiredKeys` and `MapOptionalKeys`.

Comment: I *think* the fact we want different flags on the properties means that we need to have that intersection, but if anyone knows of a way to do it without the interesection, that would be really cool.

Comment: Amazing. I got as far as extracting the keys by literal types but got stuck on the conversion to actual fields.